# Problems with alignment of Asp checkboxlist

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have an asp.net web forms page, and my checkboxlist won't work properly -
elements in checkboxlist always align vertically, but I need to make it horizontally in css.
I understand that problem in field display: block;
 But I need this to format all div, and when I add css for checkbox - check-field , it doesn't make change.
**How can I make checkboxlist element align horizontally?**
Now i have this :
[image]

But I want to align it horizontally
My code:

```html
<div id="infodif" runat="server" visible="true" class="form-style-2">
  <div class="form-style-2-heading">
    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" />
  </div>
  <label><span>First <span class="required">*</span></span><asp:TextBox ID="faminfobox" class="input-field"  runat="server"  onkeypress="return isAlphaNumericKey(event);" /></label>
  <label><span>Second <span class="required">*</span></span><asp:TextBox ID="iminfobox" class="input-field" runat="server"  onkeypress="return isAlphaNumericKey(event);" /></label>
  <label><span>Third <span class="required">*</span></span><asp:TextBox ID="otinfobox" class="input-field" runat="server" onkeypress="return isAlphaNumericKey(event);" /></label>
  <label><span>Four <span class="required">*</span></span><asp:TextBox ID="OGRNinfobox" CssClass="input-field" class="input-field" runat="server" disabled="true" Enabled="false" onkeypress="return allowOnlyNumber(event);" /></label>
  <label><span>Five <span class="required">*</span></span><asp:TextBox ID="TabNominfobox" CssClass="input-field" class="input-field" runat="server" Enabled="false" onkeypress="return allowOnlyNumber(event);" /></label>
  <label><span>CHECK</span><asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" DataValueField="idGK" CssClass="check-field" class="check-field" DataTextField="ShortName" SelectMethod="GetFinance" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"/></label>
  <label><span>Seven <span class="required">*</span></span><asp:TextBox ID="commentbox" CssClass="textarea-field" class="textarea-field" Text="Введите причину изменения" Enabled="false" runat="server"  Height="21px" /></label>
  <label><span>Eight</span><asp:DropDownList ID="sexinfodrop" runat="server" class="select-field" SelectMethod="GetSex" DataValueField="w" DataTextField="pol" EnableViewState="true" /></label>


  <label><span>&nbsp;</span><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></label>
  <label><span>&nbsp;</span><asp:Button ID="SaveBtn" Text="Сохранить" runat="server" OnClick="SaveBtn_Click" Visible="true" /><asp:Button ID="ChangeReqAf" Text="Сохранить Изменения" runat="server" OnClick="ChangeReqAf_Click" Visible="false" /></label>

</div>
```

My css:

```css
  .form-style-2{
    max-width: 800px;
    /*display: flexbox;*/
    padding: 20px 12px 10px 20px;
    font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.form-style-2-heading{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.form-style-2 label{
    display:block;
    margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
  
}
.form-style-2 label >  span{
    width: 300px;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
.form-style-2 span.required{
    color:red;
}

.form-style-2 input.input-field{
    width: 48%;
    
}


.form-style-2 .check-field {
   display: table-row;
  float: left;
 
}
```

**UPDATE :**
1. I update Css code.

2. Now i have [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use :

`RepeatLayout="Table"`  along with  `RepeatDirection="Horizontal"`

Comment: It works, but in this case i lose formatting . How can i make it without borders  and with another font?

Comment: @АндрейГолубцов paste your image after applying above attribute so that i can provide you with solution

Comment: @АндрейГолубцов its hard to guess the code until i see the compiled out put.. what you can do is in your existing css , where ever you are using `.form-style-2 label >  span` , you need to create seperate classes for `.form-style-2 label >  tr` or `.form-style-2 label >  table` or `.form-style-2 label >  td` and try to apply the same css as `.form-style-2 label >  span` because when you change the repeatlayout to `table` it will be showin in `tr` and `td` where as `flow` will be showin in span

Comment: if i have another tables - how can i rename this small table for checkbox to make css only for this? because now this checkbox take style from existing table in my page

Comment: @АндрейГолубцов you need to add a custom css to this only means my guess is you are using `form-style-2` for all the forms , so make a unique class for this form only some examples like `fom-style-onlycheckbox`

Answer (score 0):

you can use felxbox, something like this

```css
.form-style-2 {
  /*max-width: 500px;*/
  display: flex;

  font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.form-style-2-heading {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.form-style-2 label {
  display: block;
  margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
}

.form-style-2 label>span {
  width: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.form-style-2 span.required {
  color: red;
}

.form-style-2 input.input-field {
  width: 48%;
}

.form-style-2 .check-field {
  display: table-row;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="infodif" runat="server" visible="true" class="form-style-2">
  <div class="form-style-2-heading">
    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" />
  </div>
  <label><span>First <span class="required">*</span></span><asp:TextBox ID="faminfobox" class="input-field"  runat="server"  onkeypress="return isAlphaNumericKey(event);" /></label>
  <label><span>Second <span class="required">*</span></span><asp:TextBox ID="iminfobox" class="input-field" runat="server"  onkeypress="return isAlphaNumericKey(event);" /></label>
  <label><span>Third <span class="required">*</span></span><asp:TextBox ID="otinfobox" class="input-field" runat="server" onkeypress="return isAlphaNumericKey(event);" /></label>
  <label><span>Four <span class="required">*</span></span><asp:TextBox ID="OGRNinfobox" CssClass="input-field" class="input-field" runat="server" disabled="true" Enabled="false" onkeypress="return allowOnlyNumber(event);" /></label>
  <label><span>Five <span class="required">*</span></span><asp:TextBox ID="TabNominfobox" CssClass="input-field" class="input-field" runat="server" Enabled="false" onkeypress="return allowOnlyNumber(event);" /></label>
  <label><span>CHECK</span><asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" DataValueField="idGK" CssClass="check-field" class="check-field" DataTextField="ShortName" SelectMethod="GetFinance" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"/></label>
  <label><span>Seven <span class="required">*</span></span><asp:TextBox ID="commentbox" CssClass="textarea-field" class="textarea-field" Text="Введите причину изменения" Enabled="false" runat="server"  Height="21px" /></label>
  <label><span>Eight</span><asp:DropDownList ID="sexinfodrop" runat="server" class="select-field" SelectMethod="GetSex" DataValueField="w" DataTextField="pol" EnableViewState="true" /></label>


  <label><span>&nbsp;</span><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></label>
  <label><span>&nbsp;</span><asp:Button ID="SaveBtn" Text="Сохранить" runat="server" OnClick="SaveBtn_Click" Visible="true" /><asp:Button ID="ChangeReqAf" Text="Сохранить Изменения" runat="server" OnClick="ChangeReqAf_Click" Visible="false" /></label>

</div>
```

Comment: did you remove the padding and replace it with display: flex? on what browser are you testing? because ie11 done't have a good support of flexbox

Comment: yep, i make like this, but this give me nothing . i use ie to test. I have good result in checkbox if i delete display:block from .form-style-2 label , but my formatting of all div is losing  in this case. Do you have any suggestion , why it works like this?